# What does Ian say to Louise after she went into the ship?

Tags: dialogue, arrival

Can anyone help with a piece of dialogue in *Arrival*?

Louise has just met up with Ian after she goes in the ship alone. He wraps a blanket around her and ushers her into the pickup. She then explains something about a reason for all of this and Ian mutters something about being married (before?).

Can anyone give me the precise dialogue and explain what it was about?

Comment: You can find the entire script here https://www.scriptslug.com/script/arrival-2016 and check the part you want !!

Answer (score 5):

As she is put into the truck, Louise has a vision of her future with her daughter...

As the vision ends she says.

> LOUISE: I just realized why my husband left me. My husband left me.
>
> IAN: You were married?

The script can be found [**here**](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/arrival-2016.pdf) and [**here.**](http://www.cinefile.biz/script/arrival.pdf)

Comment: How do you know all the movies?